# Upload image to folder in spring mvc

Tags: spring, file, spring-mvc

I try to upload image to folder in my resource `"/resouces/images/demo.jpg"` but it could not run. Can you help to upload to my resource in spring **mvc**. If I upload to `"C://test//demo.jpg"`, It's ok.
My sample:

```
    String filename = File.separator + "resources"
                       + File.separator + "images" + File.separator
                       + filea.getOriginalFilename();
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    int readBytes = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
        System.out.println("===ddd=======");
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you try to upload the image to `/resources/images`? Do you see an error? What do the logs say? `/resources/images` will need to be a real path that exists on the filesystem and it will need to be writeable by your app.

Comment: Do you have a folder named "resources" in `c:` (or the drive from which the server is launched), containing a subfolder "images"?

Comment: @WillKeeling: I have this folder in my project, `webapp/resources/images`

Comment: @JBNizet: I want to upload image to resource in my project, and I can get the link from my database to view this image...

Comment: Your deployed application should be treated as read-only. EIther because it actually is (because it's a war file), or because you simply don't want to lose all your uploaded files when you redeploy the application. You don't store the data of your app in the resources of your app, do you? No: you use a database stored elsewhere. Uplodaded files are data, that should also be stored outside of the application.

Comment: @JBNizet: what should I do to save image and get it??.. In case Admin, I want to add a new product to my web.. and User can see it...

Comment: If you want to serve that image, then write a servlet that reads the file, and sends its bytes to the response output stream (after setting the appropriate content type: image/jpeg in this case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inject ServletContext like any other bean

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext
```

then
use

```
    String webappRoot = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
    String relativeFolder = File.separator + "resources" + File.separator
                             + "images" + File.separator
    String filename = webappRoot + relativeFolder
                       + filea.getOriginalFilename();
```